# Apache Spark - working with 2 RDDs: complement of RDDs

Tags: apache-spark

I have 2 RDDs, each is read from a different type of log file that have some data in common. So, we have RDD of type EventA and RDD of type EventB, where classes EventA and EventB inherit from Event.

What is the best way to get an RDD of type EventB with distinct events with respect to RDD of type EventA?

Logically if I formulate the question in "set theory", I am interested in the complement of the sets: RDD[EventB] ∖ RDD[EventA]. I intend to use the equals method defined in Event to infer which events are the same.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you want `subtract` or if the important data is in the keys `subtractByKey`.

basic usage:
`rdd.subtractByKey(otherRdd)`

This operation is much more efficient when the first RDD is smaller because the first RDD can be kept in memory while the second is streamed. From your question it wasn't clear if you wanted everything in `A that isn't in B` or `everything that isn't in the intersection of A and B`. So the solution for the second approach would be to union the result of the two subtractions:

```
val newRdd = rdd.subtractByKey(otherRdd).union(otherRdd.subtractByKey(rdd))
```

Comment: Is the first `rdd` in subtractByKey always stored in main memory? Right now, my `rdd` that has to go first is too large to store in main memory (which is why it is an RDD..). I have to do `rdd.subtractByKey(otherRdd)`, I can't reverse it. Do I have any options? When I run this code, it yields `ValueError: too many values to unpack`